# semantic ui button does not show up correctly

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, semantic-ui, web-frontend

I am creating a button using semantic ui css framework this is my code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/semantic.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/semantic.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/components/button.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div class="ui labeled button" tabindex="0">
<div class="ui button">
<i class="heart icon"></i> Like
</div>
<a class="ui basic label">
2,048
</a>
</div>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

result should be this:

[image]

but this is what i get

[image]

any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that the problem is into the file paths.
Try to replace them with the [CDN paths](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/semantic-ui).

Comment: which one of them should i include?